# Toilet Seat Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Let's take some regular house with a man, which has to go to the toilet every `n` minutes, requiring the seat to be up, and a woman, which has to do it every `m` minutes, requiring a seat to be down. Is there a possibility to create a `O(1)` algorithm which will output the exact number of toilet seat movements for a given period of `X` minutes? There are two different additional inputs:
1. The man always leaves the seat up after a visit.
2. The man always puts the seat down after a visit.

**Conclusion:** in the real life (which involves `n` being much more than `m`, with X->infinity), it is proven that there is no difference in a number of seat movements.

 But if a man does it more often, then a woman, it will prolong the seat life if he will just leave the seat up, but is this case one of them (or both) should probably see a doctor.
Now I know what is the best for the seat itself, but which person makes more movements - is another question (which should not be asked anyways).

Comment: By additional inputs do you mean variations on the problem or are we including a mixture of the two types of men?

Comment: The idea is to have two outputs. They are a problem variations, not a mixture.

Comment: Never knew there was an algorithm for that! to quote 'if you tinkle when you sprinkle, be sweet and wipe the seat'....

Comment: You forgot to add that the man is drinking `x` ounces of beer every `y` minutes, which will have a relatively exponential effect on how frequently he goes to the toilet and how often he actually puts the seat up

Comment: @jason: Teach a man to fish for a day, and he will learn to drink like a fish....

Comment: Are you trying to estimate the life expectancy of your toilet seat hinges?

Comment: @Steve: depends how strong the leaks are in terms of acidic corrosion which would destroy the hinges.... :)

Comment: @alemjerus, what are the constraints on the inputs? I.e., if a man goes to the bathroom every `n` minutes and `X` is < `n`, he could still go at least once. It seems like without further information (such as when they first go to the bathroom) that there isn't a single answer.

Comment: is there some heavy toilet seat action if both are in at the same time or they take turns?

Comment: @MSN: Let's say they both left the toiled exactly a second before an experiment started<br/>. @Eric: If they both should go at the same minute, let's suppose man goes first and finishes in 30 seconds, leaving his wife plenty of time to avoid messing up the algorithm;

Comment: Unless the man is married to and wants to stay married to the woman then any solution that leaved the toilet seat up after his use is moot.  Also the premise is badly flawed as some proportion of the man's toilet seat usage does require it to remain down.

Comment: @Eric: I am not sure what to make of 'heavy toilet seat action' unless a pink elephant crashed through the roof due to copious amount of drink taken.....

Comment: won't men piss on or through the seat regardless of its configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `2`, the answer is `2*floor(X/n)`. The man will always go to the bathroom with the toilet seat down and leave it down. The woman will never put it down, since it's only up when the man goes to the bathroom.

`1` is a little more tricky.

EDIT: Duh. For `1`, the answer is `2*floor(X/m)`. The toilet seat only transitions when the woman goes to the bathroom.

EDIT2: Plus or minus the initial state of the toilet.

EDIT3: My answer to 1 is only correct if `m>=n`. I'll figure out the rest later.

EDIT4: If `n>=2m`, then it's `2*floor(X/n)`, since the seat will only transition when the man goes pee. If `n>m`, I believe the answer is also `2*floor(X/n)`, but I need to work out the math.

EDIT5: So, for `2m>n>m`, the seat transitions when the man goes pee after the woman and vice versa. The sequence of man/woman visits repeats every `least_common_multiple(m, n)` minutes, so we only need to concern ourselves with what happens in that time period. The only time the seat would **not** transition when the man uses it would be if he managed to visit it twice in a row. Given that the woman is visiting **more** often than the man, between every man visit there is at least one woman visit. (Twice at the beginning or end.)

Answer 1 then becomes: `(n>m ? 2*floor(X/n) : 2*floor(X/m)) + (remainder(X/n) > remainder(X/m) ? 1 : 0)`. Or something like that.

Comment: 2 is perfectly correct, but as for 1: let's say a man has to go once per hour, and a woman once per 7 minutes. There is a bit more complicated dependency on what a man does.

Comment: Posted a more complete solution, but I gave you a vote since it's basically the same :)

Comment: @Jimmy, I'll have a better analysis tomorrow. It's really hard to type on an iPhone.

Answer (score 15):

#### Yes, there is a basic O(1) algorithm.

I start with the assumption both people start "ticking" at t=0.
I believe the solution should generalize to different starting times, but it isn't hard to extend from one "free end" of the timeline to two ends.

#### Assume n <= m.

Then our timeline looks like this (an 'x' marks a 'move', not a visit)

```
  0     m    2m    ..              t-t%m  t
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--o
W x     x     x     x     x     x     x 
M x  x    x    x       x     x    x     x?
```

So, the woman goes floor(t/m) times, and between
each time the woman goes -- in the half-open interval `(a*m, a*m+m]` --
the man goes at least once, thus flipping the seat once. For
each time that she flips the seat in an interval, he also flips it once.
However, he possibly will go once more after
her last trip, depending on their relative timings,
which you can calculate based on t modulo their respective periods.

```
total_moves = floor(t/m) * 2 + (t%m < t%n ? 1 : 0)
```

#### Now for the case n > m.

The roles of the woman and man are reversed...  the half-open interval `[a*n, a*n+n)` will always involve two moves. The remainder
of the line is `[t-t%n, t)`, in which the man goes once at the beginning,
(which is +1 move, but we counted +2 for both people's moves at t=0, which we should probably discard) and the woman goes if she has equal or less time left than he does

```
total_moves = floor(t/n) * 2 - 1 + (t%m >= t%n ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: This is more exact, but idea is the same. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is, at least when the implementation can assume that the cycle for a man and a woman is known in advance and that it doesn't change:

Start with the least common multiple of the man/woman cycle times (`lcm`). Precalculate the movements for this time period (`lcm_movements`). Now you only have to deal with your input `time` modulo `lcm`. For this you could simply set up a fixed length table containing the number of movements for every minute.

Given that `time` and `lcm` are integers in Java/C/C++/C# the actual calculation might be this:

```
return ( time / lcm ) * lcm_movements + movements[ time % lcm ];
```

Comment: This looks pretty cool.  But if the program needs to allow for input variables, then doesn't that mean that the creation of the movements array needs to be dynamic?  And shouldn't that be counted towards the efficiency of the algorithm?

Comment: are you sure finding lcm is O(1)?

Comment: Find the lcm is not O(1) with respect to the values of n and m; look for example at how it can be calculated using the Euclidean algorithm.    However, I like this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- we start at t=0 with the toilet seat down

  if man and woman arrive at the same time, then ladies first.

Let lastLadyTime := floor(X/m)*m and lastManTime := floor(X/n)*n. They represent the last time of toilet usage. The expression (lastLadyTime > lastManTime) is the same as (X%m < X%n) because by definition X%m = X - lastLadyTime and X%n = X - lastManTime.

Case: **man leaves seat down**
The lady never has to move the seat but he always needs to lift it up. Hence `floor(X/n)`.

Case: **man leaves seat up, n == m**
He will always need to lift it up and she will always need to push it down except at the very first toilet usage when she doesn't have to do anything.  Hence `2*floor(X/n) - (X < n ? 0 : 1)`

Case: **man leaves seat up, n > m**
Every time he uses it, he needs to lift it up. She only needs to push it down once after he uses it. This happens all the time except at the end if time runs out before she gets to use the toilet after him. Therefore we must minus 1 if lastManTime >= lastLadyTime (remember, ladies first). Hence  2*floor(X/n) - (lastManTime >= lastLadyTime ?  1 : 0) = `2*floor(X/n) - (X%n <= X%m ? 1 : 0)`

Case: **man leaves seat up, n < m**
Similar to n > m. Every time she uses it, she needs to push it down. He only needs to lift it up once after she uses it. This happens all the time except at the end if time runs out before he has to use the toilet after her.  Therefore we must minus 1 if lastManTime < lastLadyTime. Also one difference is that he needs to lift the seat the first time around. Hence  2*floor(X/m) - (lastManTime < lastLadyTime ?  1 : 0) + (X < n ? 0 : 1) = `2*floor(X/m) - (X%n > X%m ? 1 : 0) + (X < n ? 0 : 1)`

Answer (score 1):

If all minute variables are integers then you could do it like this:

```
int toilet_seat_movements = 0;
bool seat_up = false;

for (i = 0; i <= total_minutes; i++)
{
    if (seat_up)
    {
        if (i % woman_minutes == 0)
            toilet_seat_movements++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (i % man_minutes == 0)
            toilet_seat_movements++;
    }
}

return toilet_seat_movements;
```

Comment: This is quite simple and obvious solution, but does not give O(1), since depends on inputed minutes.

Comment: That's not O(1). It's O(n) where n == minutes_elapsed.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  Now I'm trying to understand x4u's solution... I see now how this could become quite an interesting problem.